# Grocer Project C++, iterating through a file

Tags: c++

I am having issues trying to figure out how to do this specific method that iterates through a text file, keeps track of how many times an item appears whilst not printing the item more than once, for example, the output would be:

```
Broccoli 2
Peas 4
Bananas 1
etc.
```

The python listed is just for testing, the histogram must be written in python but I am not worried about that as of yet.

###### MAIN.CPP

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void CallProcedure(string pName)
{
    char* procname = new char[pName.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, pName.c_str());

    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* my_module = PyImport_ImportModule("python");
    PyErr_Print();
    PyObject* my_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(my_module, procname);
    PyObject* my_result = PyObject_CallObject(my_function, NULL);
    Py_Finalize();

    delete[] procname;
}

int callIntFunc(string proc, string param)
{
    char* procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    char* paramval = new char[param.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(paramval, param.c_str());


    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue = nullptr, * presult = nullptr;
    
    Py_Initialize();
    
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"python");
    
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
     
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(z)", paramval);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    
    Py_Finalize();

     
    delete[] procname;
    delete[] paramval;


    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}

int callIntFunc(string proc, int param)
{
    char* procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue = nullptr, * presult = nullptr;
    
    Py_Initialize();
    
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"python");
    
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
     
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(i)", param);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_DECREF(pValue);

    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    
    Py_Finalize();
 
    delete[] procname;

    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}

void displayItemsPurchased() {
    //FINISH
}

void displaySpecificItem() {
    ifstream fin("Items.txt");
    int count = 0;
    char ch[20], item[20];
    cout << "Enter an item to display: ";
    cin >> item;
    while (fin) {
        fin >> ch;
        if (strcmp(ch, item) == 0)
            count++;
    }
    cout << item << " was bought " << count << " times today";
    fin.close(); 
}

void displayHistogram() {
    //FINISH
}

void displayMenu() {
    int userChoice;
    int i = 0;
    while (i == 0) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "***********************************************" << endl;
        cout << "1 - Display List all items purchased          *" << endl;
        cout << "2 - Get quantity of a specific item purchased *" << endl;
        cout << "3 - Display items purchased with a histogram  *" << endl;
        cout << "4 - Exit                                      *" << endl;
        cout << "***********************************************" << endl;
        cout << "Selection: ";
        cin >> userChoice;
        cout << endl;

        if (userChoice == 1) {
            displayItemsPurchased();
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (userChoice == 2) {
            displaySpecificItem();
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (userChoice == 3) {
            cout << "You selected 3";
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (userChoice == 4) {
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid selection. Try again." << endl;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    CallProcedure("printsomething");
    cout << callIntFunc("PrintMe", "House") << endl;
    cout << callIntFunc("SquareValue", 2);
    displayMenu();
    
    system("pause>0");
}
```

###### PYTHON.PY

```
import re
import string


def printsomething():
    print("Hello from python!")

def PrintMe(v):
    print("You sent me: " + v)
    return 100;

def SquareValue(v):
    return v * v
```

###### ITEMS.TXT

```
Spinach

Radishes

Broccoli

Peas

Cranberries

Broccoli

Potatoes

Cucumbers

Radishes
Cranberries

Peaches

Zucchini

Potatoes

Cranberries

Cantaloupe

Beets

Cauliflower

Cranberries

Peas

Zucchini

Peas

Onions

Potatoes

Cauliflower

Spinach

Radishes

Onions

Zucchini

Cranberries

Peaches

Yams

Zucchini

Apples

Cucumbers

Broccoli

Cranberries

Beets

Peas

Cauliflower

Potatoes

Cauliflower

Celery

Cranberries

Limes

Cranberries

Broccoli

Spinach

Broccoli

Garlic

Cauliflower

Pumpkins

Celery

Peas

Potatoes

Yams

Zucchini

Cranberries

Cantaloupe

Zucchini

Pumpkins

Cauliflower

Yams

Pears

Peaches

Apples

Zucchini

Cranberries

Zucchini

Garlic

Broccoli

Garlic

Onions

Spinach

Cucumbers

Cucumbers

Garlic

Spinach

Peaches

Cucumbers

Broccoli

Zucchini
Peas

Celery

Cucumbers

Celery

Yams

Garlic

Cucumbers

Peas

Beets

Yams

Peas

Apples

Peaches

Garlic

Celery

Garlic

Cucumbers

Garlic

Apples

Celery

Zucchini

Cucumbers

Onions
```

The method I need help with is the displayItemsPurchased() method

Comment: Why are you mixing in python code? This is a very simple task that can be done in C++ using a map.

Comment: Change the format of elements of your `ITEMS.txt` file! It's way too long!

Comment: I agree with @ChrisMM.

Comment: All that Python stuff appears to have nothing whatsoever to do with your problem. Remove it.

Comment: In this site, we expect askers to provide a [mre]. You should remove all the stuff unrelated to the current problem to keep the example **minimal**.

Comment: Define a data structure that represents all purchases (`std::map<std::string, int>` springs to mind). Read the file into this structure when the program starts.

Comment: Furthermore, not only this contains unrelated but useless  when not incorrect code: `void main` is plain wrong, it should be `int main`, `system("pause>0");` only prevents the code to be tested on a platform lacking `pause` and has nothing to do in a [mre]. In `callIntFunc`, `procname` is plain useless: you could directly use `proc.c_str()`... Please strip that all to a [mre] if you want answers

Comment: @OP Honestly, this can be done in C++ with less than 10 lines of code, maybe even 5 lines of code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 5 seems about right: https://godbolt.org/z/a3YefK6vd

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this very easily with C++ only using fstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");

    std::vector<std::string> item_names;
    std::vector<int> item_counts;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        if (line.empty()) continue;

        item_names.push_back(line);
        item_counts.push_back(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < item_names.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            if (line == item_names[i])
            {
                item_counts[i]++;
                item_names.pop_back();
                item_counts.pop_back();

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < item_names.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i + 1 << ". " << item_names[i] << ": " << item_counts[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This code reads the data stored in "input.txt" and then prints out the number of occurrences of all the items in "input.txt".

**For example:**

### input.txt

```
Spinach
Radishes
Broccoli
Peas
Cranberries
Broccoli
Potatoes
Cucumbers
Radishes
Cranberries
Peaches
Zucchini
Potatoes
Cranberries
Cantaloupe
Beets
Cauliflower
Cranberries
```

### output

```
1. Spinach: 1
2. Radishes: 2
3. Broccoli: 2
4. Peas: 1
5. Cranberries: 4
6. Potatoes: 2
7. Cucumbers: 1
8. Peaches: 1
9. Zucchini: 1
10. Cantaloupe: 1
11. Beets: 1
12. Cauliflower: 1
```

The solution for this is given in the comments too, and it is way smaller. But it doesn't really read from any .txt file. Instead, it takes input from the user directly.

Comment: Using a `std::map<std::string, int>` is much shorter than this solution.  A map is tailor-made for this type of work, rather than two separate vectors.

Comment: This is just my way of doing it. Also, the OP asked to take input from a file, but the solution in the comments doesn't do that.

Comment: *This is just my way of doing it* -- Since you did see the solution in the comments, you could have mentioned what that solution does, since it is much shorter than your version.  Maybe the OP would like to know this.

Comment: Alright, I added it at the end.

Comment: _"But it doesn't really read from any .txt file. Instead, it takes input from the user directly."_ - If you look closely at the comments in the code I put as an example in the comment section I think you'll find that it's just a matter of uncommenting one line and replacing `std::cin` with `ifs` to make it read from `ITEMS.TXT` instead.